# JavaFX ToggleButton resizes when Icon is applied

Tags: javafx, togglebutton, scenebuilder

Short deescription:

My `ToggleButtons` resize when I apply the Image for them.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

In depth:

I have a GridLayout filled with `ToggleButtons`. In code, this `ToggleButtons` get a `BufferedImage` to have a skin:

```
// Top Left
BufferedImage bImage = Thumbnails
.of(Watermarker.class.getResourceAsStream("view/img/toggle_top_left.png"))
.size(20, 20).asBufferedImage();
Image fxImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bImage, null);
this.posTopLeft.setGraphic(new ImageView(fxImage));
// Repeated for each Button
```

Without applying an `Image` it works like so:
[Without images on ToggleButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFHyo.png)

With images, it is like shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxwzy.png)

What do I have to do to prevent this resizing?

The Buttons are set to 25x25 in size (SceneBuilder)
In code, I resize the icons from their 25x25 to 20x20 before assigning.

Comment: Also no need to use `SwingFXUtils`. You can use standard `Image`  class from JavaFX API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
toggleButton.setStyle("-fx-min-width:25;");
```

or

```
toggleButton.minWidthProperty().bind(new SimpleDoubleProperty(25));
```

Comment: Works perfect! The icons make it feel resized again, but deeper analyzing showed: it didn't! Thank you!